# Javascript Switch Statement Broken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I'm very confused at the moment. I have a simple switch statement in React that is misbehaving and I don't know why.

Check this out:

```
alterHandler(keyName, value, profileType){
    const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    console.log('inside alterHandler in Profile')
    console.log('value of profileType: ', profileType)
    console.log('profileType equals local: ', profileType=='local')
    console.log('profileType equals db: ', profileType=='db')
    switch (profileType){
      case 'local':
        console.log('23235235235123523t2346 case local')
        newState['local'][keyName] = value;
      case 'db':
        console.log('23235235235123523t2346 case db')
        newState['db'][keyName] = value;
      case 'n/a':
        newState[keyName] = value;
      default:
        if(keyName=='animalType'){
          newState['showForward'] = true;
        }
        this.setState(newState, ()=>{
          console.log('after setting state in alterHandler 
          in Profile and value: ', this.state)
        });
    }
  }
```

If I call alterHandler with

```
onChange={(e)=>{this.props.alterHandler('personalName', e.target.value, 'local')}}
```

in an input statement,

I get the following output:

```
 value of profileType:  local index.js:216
 profileType equals local:  true index.js:217
 profileType equals db:     false index.js:218
 case local index.js:221
 case db  index.js:224
```

So case "db" is firing even though `profileType` is 'local'!

What in the wide wide world of sports is going on here?

Comment: Don't forget to end each case with `break;`, or you'll fall through to the next case.

Comment: Might want some `break`s up in there.

Comment: Read some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [`switch` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Specifically, this section:

> The optional `break` statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If `break` is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement.

So, if you don`t add a`break`clause, the program will not exit the`switch`scope and the`default` action will be run since it doesn't know that a clause has already matched.

Comment: Thanks - I'm too used to `break`  being used to stop execution earlier as opposed to an end of clause statement. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With switch statements when you create a `case`, the switch will go through the cases till it finds one that is true. Once it finds this case it will start executing code from there. The problem is that it will just keep going into other cases unless you `break` out of the switch statement.

In your switch statement

```
    switch (profileType){
      case 'local':
```

It executes everything in local and then continues onto db because you dont have `break;`.